# Several android attributes not resolved in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-styles

Every attribute prefaced by "android:" in my styles.xml below is giving me a "cannot resolve symbol" error. It's been like this for a while so I'm not sure where it began and what causes it. Removing "android:" gives me a "resource linking failed" error in the build log.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="TheoTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/lightBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="TheoTheme.ActionBarReverse" parent="TheoTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
</style>

<style name="PurpleTheme" parent="TheoTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Accent2</item>
</style>

<style name="ChatRoomTheme" parent="TheoTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Accent</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginTheme" parent="TheoTheme" >
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="RegisterTheme" parent="TheoTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker.Logo">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="gravity">center</item>

</style>

<style name="GenericProgressBackground" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
<style name="GenericProgressIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DMTheme.AppTheme" parent="ChatRoomTheme" />
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        ReleaseKey {
            file('X:\\Documents\\All\\Creative\\Programming\\Projects\\KeyStore\\TheoKeyStore.jks')

        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.meettheo.theo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.ReleaseKey
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.ReleaseKey
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}



dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Invalidating/cleaning/rebuilding does not work. What did I break to make this happen?

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file ?

Comment: Added. Note that I've attempted commenting out all dependencies, building, then adding  them back and rebuilding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try the following solution:

- Back up project
- Delete the .idea folder and .iml files
- Relaunch Android Studio and re-import the project.

For some people it will work to just remove all the libraries from .idea folder and re-sync Gradle.

If none of these are working you always could reinstall the complete studio which, depending on your network speed, wouldn't take that long.

Comment: I did end up deleting the settings folder and reinstalling. I'll give you the bounty so other people can see this solution.

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

go to your gradle, comment out the support libraries you're using, sync your project and you will get errors. Then uncomment the libraries and sync again. Now the project will be successfully built, and chances are your problem will be resolved. I'm not sure how this is caused in the first place, but the above solution has worked for me in the past when caches/clean/rebuilt would fail.

Edit: Also depending on the property you might want to add app: instead of android:

Comment: Oddly enough, commenting them out and syncing didn't give me any build errors. Unfortunately bringing them back and syncing again didn't fix my problem either.

Comment: sorry to hear it didn't help. Hopefully, someone else will have an alternative to offer

Answer (score 0):

I've had that issue for some time and that also pissed me off.

Guess what's the solution? As simple as re-importing the project again via `File -> Open`:

[image]

Thereafter all of the resources were correctly resolved.

Comment: Ugh. I had high hopes for this answer but this didn't work either.

Comment: @aedgar777, that's a pity. Still, will leave this answer here, might be helpful for other guys.