# Android studio cannot resolve any symbol after update

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I updated Android studio canary to the 3.5 version. After that I updated gradle. In my gradle-wrapper.properties i have this now:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

and in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha03'
    }
```

Problem: All my classes now show errors and It cannot resolve any symbol (like TextView, String, List, ArrayList, Log and so on). I think I tried everything:

- To clean project and rebuild
- To delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folders
- To delete `modules.xml` inside `.idea` folder
- To Sync gradle again
- To invalidate cache and restart Android Studio

But still not working. I can't figure out it. Any other solution?

Update: 
Weird fact. I can build the project and start the app anyway. Also with a lot of errors

Comment: Could also try to delete the .iml files and reimport the project. Make sure to back-up first

Comment: Where are the .iml files? I don't have any .iml files inside .idea folder

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818118/7143587 , there are also some other options you might consider